# Django Object not Saving

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am currently trying to save a Django object. My code looks like this

```
boxscore = BoxScore.objects.create(**defaults)
print(defaults)
input(boxscore)
```

Here's the output:

```
{'away_first': 0, 'away_second': 6, 'away_third': 7, 'away_fourth': 17, 'away_final': 30, 'home_first': 0, 'home_second': 7, 'home_third': 0, 'home_fourth': 7, 'home_final': 14}
BoxScore object (190)
```

Here's my admin:

```
@admin.register(BoxScore)
class BoxScoreAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Here's the model:

```
class BoxScore(Base):
    home_final = models.IntegerField()
    away_final = models.IntegerField()
    home_first = models.IntegerField()
    away_first = models.IntegerField()
    home_second = models.IntegerField()
    away_second = models.IntegerField()
    home_third = models.IntegerField()
    away_third = models.IntegerField()
    home_fourth = models.IntegerField()
    away_fourth = models.IntegerField()
    home_ot = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    away_ot = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Here's the whole helper function if that is relevant.

```
def create_boxscore(df):
    defaults = {
        'away_first': int(df.at[0, '1']),
        'away_second': int(df.at[0, '2']),
        'away_third': int(df.at[0, '3']),
        'away_fourth': int(df.at[0, '4']),
        'away_final': int(df.at[0, 'Final']),
        'home_first': int(df.at[1, '1']),
        'home_second': int(df.at[1, '2']),
        'home_third': int(df.at[1, '3']),
        'home_fourth': int(df.at[1, '4']),
        'home_final': int(df.at[1, 'Final']),
    }
    try:
        defaults['home_ot'] = int(df.at[1, 'OT'])
        defaults['away_ot'] = int(df.at[0, 'OT'])
    except:
        pass
    boxscore = BoxScore(**defaults)
    boxscore.save()
    return boxscore
```

However, nothing is showing in Django admin as being saved in the database. Why would this be and how do I fix it?

Update: I queried the database and confirmed nothing is being saved so it is not a Django admin display issue.

Update 2: If I run the sample above separately, it saves fine. However, if it is run within a helper function, nothing saves. Does being in a helper function cause saving difficulties?

Update 3: In the main function, I ran this line of code and nothing was saved:

```
if 'Final' in dfs[i].columns and '4' in dfs[i].columns:
    defaults = {'away_first': 0, 'away_second': 6, 'away_third': 7, 
    'away_fourth': 17, 'away_final': 30, 'home_first': 0, 'home_second': 7, 
    'home_third': 0, 'home_fourth': 7, 'home_final': 14}
    boxscore = BoxScore.objects.create(**defaults)
    input(boxscore)
```

But this was still outputted so I know it's reaching that line of code:

```
BoxScore object (200)
```

Comment: Have you registered your models in your `admin.py`?

Comment: @JPG yes. Here is the code for that 

```@admin.register(BoxScore)
class BoxScoreAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
     pass```

Comment: Edit your question and add relevant information.